# Applying CSS to both attribute and media query

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, dry

Hi I have duplicate css code that I want to apply to a media query as well as a html attribute.

For example

```
@media only screen and (max-width 729px)
    font-size: 1.5em
    font-weight: normal
.mobile-view
    font-size: 1.5em
    font-weight: normal
```

I am using SASS and wondering if there's a way to bundle these together to keep DRY (Don't repeat yourself)

Comment: If specifying a property by targeting the HTML element, you don't need to specify it again in your media query unless you specifically overwrote the property elsewhere in your CSS. Plus, don't forget your parenthese `{ }`

Comment: well the issue is that .mobile-view won't apply for desktop so that's when the media query will kick in. Also haha i'm using sass which doesn't need parenthese :)

Comment: What I mean to say is that if the `.mobile-view` class only applies when the media query is active, why specify the same values in two places?

Comment: You can't apply properties to a media query. A media query (neither a `@media` at-rule) is not a style rule. Where exactly do you want to apply these styles? Maybe if you expressed it in sample CSS output instead of what you've tried in Sass it might be clearer.

Comment: well ultimately, I want to have two views. one for mobile and one for desktop, and just have the desktop view responsive, so that when the media query condition hits, it'll apply the same css as the mobile view

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mixin:

```
@mixin mobileFont() {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
@media only screen and (max-width 729px){
    @include mobileFont();
}
.mobile-view{
    @include mobileFont();
}
```

However it doesn't get rendered DRY...

Comment: It's not possible to make the output DRY anyway, CSS won't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Sass expects the nested item to correspond to the parent object. So, if you method was used it would compile to something like:

```
.parent @media only screen and (max-width: 729px) .mobile-view { 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal
}
```

If you want to group multiple elements, you could do this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 729px) {
    .item-one, 
    .item-two,
    .item-three .child {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
}
```

Comment: well I know there is a way for Sass to apply css to multiple properties. Take for example
`.mobile-view, .desktop-view{ font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: normal}`
that will apply the css to both properties. however when i use the same tactic with @media queries it doesn't work :(

Comment: What if you triedddddd...

`@media screen and (max-width: 729px) { .desktop-view, .mobile-view { font-weight: normal; font-size: 1.5em; } }`.

Comment: ^ this won't catch a lot of mobile-device cases like iPad or even retina display iPad mini or something. They won't hit the media query and never get the mobile-view css, because (take for example) iPad's max-width is larger than 729px

Comment: You can set it based on pixel ratio, if you're looking to set it for iPad specifically. That being said, if you've added the `viewport` meta tag it will still work.

Comment: hmmm but with viewport the new retina ipad's will default to 1024x768 resolution? I can certainly change the media query to look specifically for ipads but that's a bit of a shame, since i can already tell based on the `.mobile-view` property. EDIT: I'll admit I don't have too much experience with the viewport meta tag. I'll look into it and see if I can use it here.